# Why is the ping address different

Tags: ping

I tried to ping google.com and this is what happened:

```
ping www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (74.125.224.82) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google, being so big, has many servers. When you ping www.google.com, you are pinging a DNS entry that is a CNAME, which is an alias that points to multiple servers, which operate in a round-robin setup. So if you ping it again, you may not get the same server to respond (once your DNS cache clears). That CNAME/DNS round robin setup servers up one server after another for request after request. This also allows them to bring a server down for whatever reason, like maintenance, and not skip a beat.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of records associated to google.com -- [www.who.is/dns/google.com/](http://www.who.is/dns/google.com/)

Also see, [Robtex summary for www.l.google.com](http://www.robtex.com/dns/www.l.google.com.html#summary).

And, this [graphical view of **`www.google.com`**](http://www.robtex.com/dns/www.google.com.html#graph)
showing the [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) reference `www.l.google.com`.

Comment: And just to be clear, the "www.l.google.com" is the [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) lookup of the IP 74.125.224.82.

Comment: And, adding to that, if you were to do the same `ping` from some other geographic location, the IP address is likely to be different.